# How to fix java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException error?

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

I am getting following error when I run my spring boot service in production as windows service. Service exe is created by [Jar2exe](https://www.jar2exe.com/).

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'mindbodyApplication': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'mindBodyClientService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindBodyClientServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.rossmoor.mindbody.services.web.MindBodyClientServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@18769467]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:734)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.rossmoor.mindbody.MindbodyApplication.main(MindbodyApplication.java:43)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mindBodyClientServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.rossmoor.mindbody.services.web.MindBodyClientServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@18769467]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1391)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1311)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
    ... 28 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.rossmoor.mindbody.services.web.MindBodyClientServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@18769467]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267)
    ... 40 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3402)
    at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2504)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:467)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 46 more
```

Strange thing is it runs properly when I run it through Intellij Idea on production machine.
Both service exe and code in Intellij Idea work properly on my development machine.
Here is my build.gradle file :

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.1'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
//  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
//  developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'

//  // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup.okhttp3/okhttp
//  implementation group: 'com.squareup.okhttp3', name: 'okhttp', version: '4.10.0'

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '5.6.9.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/antlr/antlr
    implementation group: 'antlr', name: 'antlr', version: '2.7.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml/classmate
    implementation group: 'com.fasterxml', name: 'classmate', version: '1.5.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.activation/javax.activation-api
    implementation group: 'javax.activation', name: 'javax.activation-api', version: '1.2.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.persistence/javax.persistence-api
    implementation group: 'javax.persistence', name: 'javax.persistence-api', version: '2.2'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api
    implementation group: 'javax.xml.bind', name: 'jaxb-api', version: '2.3.1'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy
    implementation group: 'net.bytebuddy', name: 'byte-buddy', version: '1.12.12'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.glassfish.jaxb/jaxb-runtime
    implementation group: 'org.glassfish.jaxb', name: 'jaxb-runtime', version: '4.0.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.common/hibernate-commons-annotations
    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.common', name: 'hibernate-commons-annotations', version: '6.0.2.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss/jandex
    implementation group: 'org.jboss', name: 'jandex', version: '2.4.3.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.logging/jboss-logging
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.logging', name: 'jboss-logging', version: '3.5.0.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction/jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec
    implementation group: 'org.jboss.spec.javax.transaction', name: 'jboss-transaction-api_1.2_spec', version: '1.1.1.Final'

    implementation files('lib/connection-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/Utils-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/TinyLog-2.0.0.1.jar')
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class that your mindBodyClientServiceImpl is using (indirectly) is org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException.

This comes from your build.gradle:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

Since you have declared as compileOnly here:

```
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
```

but apparently the JSONException is used at run time, it makes your app fail when packaging with Jar2exe. The solution to this could be to include the whole dependency like so:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

Just a blind guess, but probably your application could fail again, but this time at least you can see the JSONException and fix the underlying issue.

Answer (score 18):

Starting with SpringBoot 2.4 the dependency

```
org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor
```

is no longer contained in the resulting fat-jar ([Spring Boot 2.4 Release Notes](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.4-Release-Notes#jar-optimizations)).

> Jar Optimizations
>
> When generating runnable Spring Boot jars, empty starter dependencies will now be automatically removed. Since most starters only provide transitive dependencies, there is little point in packaging them in the final jar.
>
> Spring Boot annotation processors are also removed as well as they are only useful during the build. These are spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor and spring-boot-configuration-processor.

If the exception is thrown in you own code, check that you are not using

```
org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject
```

If you are using those, replace them, e.g.:

```
org.json.JSONException
org.json.JSONObject
```

You might need to include the related [dependency](https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.json/json), e.g. (or newer):

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.json</groupId>
  <artifactId>json</artifactId>
  <version>20220924</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Same mistake, worked like a charm!

Comment: Live saver answer

Answer (score 0):

For me, Same issue occurs in sit environment and jar 'spring-boot-configuration-processor' classes (JSONException,JSONObject) creating issues. so have replaced with org.json classes and issue resolved

Comment: It's better to leave these kind of comments on the post it self