# The problem of starting the jar file spring boot kafka

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, exception, apache-kafka

I'm doing a bot telegram on Spring boot using kafka, I'm building a project in Inteligi IDEA, everything is fine, but as soon as I try to run the jar file, an error crashes, I provide the log below.

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-09-05 11:08:53.984 ERROR 17732 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'kafkaConsumerServiceImpl': Lookup method resolution failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.bot.hello.service.impl.KafkaConsumerServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@32a1bec0]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:289) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineConstructorsFromBeanPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1302) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1219) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:955) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:147) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:731) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:408) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:307) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1303) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1292) ~[spring-boot-2.7.8.jar!/:2.7.8]
        at com.bot.hello.HelloBotApplication.main(HelloBotApplication.java:24) ~[classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:578) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49) ~[hello-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108) ~[hello-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58) ~[hello-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65) ~[hello-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [com.bot.hello.service.impl.KafkaConsumerServiceImpl] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader@32a1bec0]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:485) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:321) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.determineCandidateConstructors(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:267) ~[spring-beans-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        ... 24 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONException
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:3502) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:3527) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:2112) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.findConcreteMethodsOnInterfaces(ReflectionUtils.java:495) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:468) ~[spring-core-5.3.25.jar!/:5.3.25]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException
        at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151) ~[hello-bot-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
        at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521) ~[na:na]
        ... 32 common frames omitted
```

I tried adding various dependencies like spring aop, spring web flux, nothing helped

Comment: Depending which Spring Boot version you are using this answer should help you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74191955/6068297

Comment: Let me guess you decied to export the jar using the IDe instead of your maven/gradle build tool. Don't use maven or gradle so that the proper jar gets crerated.

Answer (score -1):

The error message indicates a **java.lang.ClassNotFoundException** for the class **org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONException**. This particular exception class is part of **spring-boot-configuration-processor**, which aids in creating metadata for your custom properties to get support in IDEs.

However, it's unusual for your application to need this class at runtime unless you're explicitly using it. There are several potential reasons and solutions for this:

1. **Check Dependencies**: Ensure you're using the right versions of **Spring Boot** and **Kafka** dependencies in your **pom.xml** or **build.gradle**.
2. **Examine KafkaConsumerServiceImpl**: The main error appears to be related to KafkaConsumerServiceImpl. Check to see if there's any direct or indirect reference to JSONException in this class or its parent classes/interfaces.
3. **Invalidate caches and restart Intellij**: from top menu follow this path `File >> Invalidate Caches...` and **tick all the options** and press **"Invalidate and Restart"**
4. **Clean and Rebuild**: Sometimes, IDEs or build tools might have issues with caching or corrupt build outputs. Perform a clean and rebuild of your project. For maven, run
   `mvn clean install` And for gradl, run this `gradlew clean build`.
5. **Spring Boot Configuration Processor**: If you are using spring-boot-configuration-processor in your project for creating metadata, then make sure it's a provided dependency or in the optional scope, so it doesn't get included in the runtime classpath of the fat jar. This is because it's typically only needed at compile time.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
    <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>
```

6. **Shadowed Dependencies**: If you're using a plugin to create a fat jar (like the Spring Boot Maven Plugin or the Shadow plugin for Gradle), there can be issues with how dependencies are bundled or shadowed. Double-check your packaging configuration to ensure dependencies aren't being unintentionally omitted or overwritten.
7. **Spring Boot Version**: Check if you're using the right version of Spring Boot. You can go to the **Spring Boot Initializr** website, select your required dependencies, and it will suggest the compatible **Spring Boot version**.
8. **Spring AOP and WebFlux**: Adding these dependencies might not be related to the issue. Unless you have a clear reason to add them, you might want to revert those changes.